# Create a gif animation for imageview

Tags: android, animation, gif

I'm very new to android animation.

I want to create a gif animation like this:

[image]

I want to show this animation as a progress bar on an imageview.
Instead of using a gif file, I want to create an animation file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way nowadays is to use lottie.
https://airbnb.design/lottie/

Alternatively, you could implement a custom view and animate the loading process in the `onDraw(canvas: Canvas)` method, it you want to learn how to implement custom views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to create an animation XML file of the above gif.